# mysql group by clause to find multiple hits

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with two columns, `user_1` and `user_2`. The column data might have data like the following:

`user_1 | user_2
foo     | bar
foo     | baz
def     | bar
abc     | def
foo     | bar
abc     | def`

I'm interested in writing a query where `user_1` only matched with one instance of `user_2`, even if it was on multiple occasions. So in this case, `abc` and `def` occurred twice, and `abc` did not have any other `user_2` matchups, so that would be a hit. `def` and `bar` matched so that would return a count of 2 total with the aforementioned `abc` match. `foo` would not match in this query because it has at least more than 1 instance where `user_2` is not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM table_name
       GROUP BY user_1, user_2) AS temp
GROUP BY user_1
HAVING count(user_2) = 1;
```